# how to exclude negative numbers from average calculation in while loop

Tags: java, netbeans

I have a program that accepts user inputs and calculate Max, Min, and Average. The program closes when the user inputs any negative number. How do i exclude the negative number from the average calculation? Here is what i have so far.

```
    // variable
    double n = 1;
    double ave = 0;
    double sum = 0;
    double max = Double.MIN_VALUE; 
    double min = Double.MAX_VALUE ;
    int count = 0;
    double neg;

//creat scanner object
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


//loop
while (n > 0) { 

System.out.print("Input an income (any negative number to quit): "); 
n = input.nextDouble();

sum = sum + n;
count++;
ave = sum / count;

if(n<0) neg = n;
if(n>max && n >= 0 ) max = n;
if(n<min && n >= 0) min = n;
if(n>0) ave = n; }


   System.out.print(" Average " + ave + "\n Maximum " + max + "\n Minimum " + min);

}
```

}

Comment: I see that you know how to use `if`. So what are you stuck on?

Comment: Take a look at the `break` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Add an `if` condition:

```
n = input.nextDouble();

if(n < 0)
    break;

sum = sum + n;
```

Comment: Why so? it will keep looping till  input are positives.

Comment: So will `while (true)`. Unless you're trying to break on `n == 0`, which seems wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The following code only sums the input numbers when n is not negative.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double n = 1;
        double ave = 0;
        double sum = 0;
        double max = Double.MIN_VALUE;
        double min = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        int count = 0;
        double neg;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        // loop
        while (n > 0) {

            System.out.print("Input an income (any negative number to quit): ");
            n = input.nextDouble();
            if(n >= 0){
              sum = sum + n;
              count++;
            }
            if (n < 0)
                neg = n;

            if (n > max && n >= 0)
                max = n;
            if (n < min && n >= 0)
                min = n;
            if (n > 0)
                ave = n;
        }

        System.out.print(" Average " + ave + "\n Maximum " + max
                + "\n Minimum " + min);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
double n = 1;
double ave = 0;
double sum = 0;
double max = Double.MIN_VALUE; 
double min = Double.MAX_VALUE ;
int count = 0;

// create scanner object
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

// loop until n is negative
while (n >= 0) { 
    System.out.print("Input an income (any negative number to quit): "); 
    n = input.nextDouble();

    if (n >= 0) {
        if (n > max) max = n;
        if (n < min) min = n;
        sum = sum + n;
        count++;
    }
}

if (count > 0)
    ave = sum / (double) count;

System.out.print(" Average " + ave + "\n Maximum " + max + "\n Minimum " + min);
```